# Segmentation fault FILE

Tags: c

Cuanto intento hacer un ftell de mi puntero a FILE ´em´ (empleados) en la funcion ´createTablekeyEmployee(fpEmployee,tableKey);´se crea un error de segmentacion, pero eh revisado el codigo y al parecerse en las funciones de creacion y apertura de los FILE se estan creando bien.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "updateFilePrototipe.h"

int main()
{
FILE *fpEmployee,
     *fpStudent;
employee regEm;
student regStud;
long tableKey[20];

printf("Test Update File\n");

if(!openFile(fpStudent,FileStudent,"r+b",!CON_SIM_MSJ))
{
    createFileEstudent();
    if(!openFile(fpStudent,FileStudent,"r+b",CON_SIM_MSJ))
        return 1;
}
if(!openFile(fpEmployee,FileEmployee,"r+b",!CON_SIM_MSJ))
{
    createFileEmployee();
    if(!openFile(fpEmployee,FileEmployee,"r+b",CON_SIM_MSJ))
    {
       fclose(fpStudent);
       return 1;
    }
}

createTablekeyEmployee(fpEmployee,tableKey);
showFileStudent(fpStudent);
showFileEmployee(fpEmployee);

fread(&regStud,1,sizeof(regStud),fpStudent);
while(!feof(fpStudent))
{
    if(regStud.average >= 7)
        updateEmployee(searchKey(regStud.dni,tableKey),fpEmployee);

    fread(&regStud,1,sizeof(regStud),fpStudent);
}

showFileStudent(fpStudent);
showFileEmployee(fpEmployee);

fclose(fpStudent);
fclose(fpEmployee);
return 0;
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include "updateFilePrototipe.h"

void createFileEmployee()
{
FILE *fp;
employee reg[] = {{87143658L, "Allende","Miguel",7.5},
             {30589425L,"Brito","Claudio",8},
             {46558892L,"Cena","Marcelo",8.9},
             {79815612L,"Dominguez","Diego",6.89},
             {46868278L,"Franzoi","Maximiliano",4.36},
             {32589614L,"Herrera","Cristobal",7.5},
             {47896425L,"Merlo","Micaela",8.55},
             {98713469L,"Oviedo","Cesar",6},
             {16887451L,"Pagnutti","Jose",8.98},
             {91649487L,"Perez","Leandro",7.39},
             {81659417L,"Recalde","Jose",7.28},
             {87952123L,"Recalde","Camila",5.56},
             {32139745L,"Rodriguez","Fabiana",7},
             {97962146L,"Romero","Johana",8.78},
             {34562501L,"Solla","Tamara",7.29},
             {16549654L,"Sosa","Federico",4.89},
             {66547893L,"Spinelli","Ezequiel",6.78},
             {21656154L,"Tapia","Jorge",8.56},
             {54514964L,"Torres","Mario",7.89},
             {22366985L,"Vizzoni","Daniela",6.56}};
fp = fopen(FileEmployee,"wb");
if(fp)
{
    fwrite(reg,1,sizeof(reg),fp);
}
fclose(fp);
}

void createFileEstudent()
{
FILE *fp;
student reg[] = {{87143658L, "Allende","Miguel",7000},
             {30589425L,"Brito","Claudio",8000},
             {46558892L,"Cena","Marcelo",9005},
             {79815612L,"Dominguez","Diego",6000},
             {46868278L,"Franzoi","Maximiliano",4500},
             {32589614L,"Herrera","Cristobal",7500},
             {47896425L,"Merlo","Micaela",8055},
             {98713469L,"Oviedo","Cesar",6750},
             {16887451L,"Pagnutti","Jose",8980},
             {91649487L,"Perez","Leandro",7039},
             {81659417L,"Recalde","Jose",7828},
             {87952123L,"Recalde","Camila",5556},
             {32139745L,"Rodriguez","Fabiana",7236},
             {97962146L,"Romero","Johana",8356},
             {34562501L,"Solla","Tamara",7429},
             {16549654L,"Sosa","Federico",4089},
             {66547893L,"Spinelli","Ezequiel",6678},
             {21656154L,"Tapia","Jorge",8756},
             {54514964L,"Torres","Mario",7489},
             {22366985L,"Vizzoni","Daniela",6456}};

fp = fopen(FileStudent,"wb");
if(fp)
{
    fwrite(reg,1,sizeof(reg),fp);
}
fclose(fp);
}

int openFile(FILE *fp,const char *name,const char *mode,int CON_SIN)
{
fp = fopen(name,mode);

if(!fp)
{
    if(CON_SIN)
        fprintf(stderr,"No se pudo abrir %s, en modo %s",name,mode);
    return 0;
}
return 1;
}

void createTablekeyEmployee(FILE *em,long *vec)
{
employee reg;
long actualPos = ftell(em);

fread(&reg,1,sizeof(reg),em);
while(!feof(em) && vec)
{
    *vec = reg.dni;
    vec ++;
    fread(&reg,1,sizeof(reg),em);
}
fseek(em,actualPos,SEEK_SET);
}

int searchKey(const long key, long vec[])
{
int i = 0;
while(vec[i] != key && i < TAM_TABLE)
{
    i ++;
}
return vec ? i : -1;
}

void updateEmployee(const int key,FILE *em)
{
employee reg;

fseek(em,key * (long)sizeof(employee),SEEK_SET);
fread(&reg,1,sizeof(reg),em);
reg.salary *= 1.728;
fseek(em,key * (long)sizeof(employee),SEEK_SET);
fwrite(&reg,1,sizeof(reg),em);
fseek(em,0L,SEEK_SET);
}

void showFileEmployee(FILE *em)
{
employee reg;
long actualPos = ftell(em);

fread(&reg,1,sizeof(reg),em);
showEmployee(NULL);
while(!feof(em))
{
   showEmployee(&reg);
   fread(&reg,1,sizeof(reg),em);
}

fseek(em,actualPos,SEEK_SET);
}

void showEmployee(employee *d)
{
if(!d)
    printf("DNI        NOMBRE          APELLIDO       SUELDO");
else
    printf("%ld        %s               %s            %lf",d->dni,d->name,d-        >surName,d->salary);
}

void showFileStudent(FILE *st)
{
 student reg;
 long actualPos = ftell(st);

fread(&reg,1,sizeof(reg),st);
showStudent(NULL);
while(!feof(st))
{
   showStudent(&reg);
   fread(&reg,1,sizeof(reg),st);
}

fseek(st,actualPos,SEEK_SET);
}

void showStudent(student *d)
{
if(!d)
    printf("DNI        NOMBRE          APELLIDO       PROMEDIO");
else
    printf("%ld        %s               %s            %f",d->dni,d->name,d->surName,d->average);
}




#define FileEmployee "employee"
#define FileStudent  "student"
#define CON_SIM_MSJ 1
#define TAM_TABLE 20
typedef struct
{
long dni;
char name[51],
     surName[51];
double salary;
}employee;

typedef struct
{
long dni;
char name[51],
     surName[51];
float average;
}student;

void createFileEmployee();
void createFileEstudent();
int openFile(FILE *fp,const char *name,const char *mode,int CON_SIN);
void createTablekeyEmployee(FILE *em,long *vec);
int searchKey(const long key, long vec[]);
void updateEmployee(const int key,FILE *em);
void showFileEmployee(FILE *em);
void showEmployee(employee *d);
void showFileStudent(FILE *st);
void showStudent(student *d);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos a ver este problema sin utilizar punteros. ¿Qué valor imprime el ejemplo siguiente?

```
void func(int valor)
{ valor = 3; }

int main()
{
  int var = 0;
  func(var);

  printf("%d",var);
}
```

La respuesta correcta es 0, ya que los cambios realizados dentro de func son meramente locales. Si ahora introducimos punteros...

```
void func1(int* valor)
{ valor = 3; }

void func2(int* valor)
{ *valor = 3; }

int main()
{
  int var = 0;
  func1(&var);
  printf("%d",var);

  func2(&var);
  printf("%d",var);
}
```

El resultado será 03. Esto es porque `func` realiza cambios sobre el propio puntero y eso no dejan de ser cambios locales, mientras que `func2` realiza cambios sobre la memoria apuntada, cambios que sí se van a ver reflejados fuera de la función. No se si se aprecia la diferencia.

En tu caso el problema es el siguiente:

```
int openFile(FILE *fp,const char *name,const char *mode,int CON_SIN)
{
  fp = fopen(name,mode);

  if(!fp)
  {
    if(CON_SIN)
        fprintf(stderr,"No se pudo abrir %s, en modo %s",name,mode);
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

`fp` es una variable local, luego todos los cambios que realices sobre dicha variable van a ser implícitamente locales. Y desgraciadamente cambiar la dirección de memoria a la que apunta el puntero es un cambio local que no tendrá ningún efecto fuera de la función.

Tienes dos posibles soluciones al problema:

- Devolver fp con el return, de tal forma que si devuelves 0 se presupone que el fichero no ha podido abrirse.
- Pasar `fp` como argumento en forma de puntero doble. De esta forma los cambios de direción del puntero simple se verán reflejados fuera de la función.

**Devolver fp**

```
FILE* openFile(const char *name,const char *mode,int CON_SIN)
{
  FILE* fp = fopen(name,mode);

  if(!fp)
  {
    if(CON_SIN)
        fprintf(stderr,"No se pudo abrir %s, en modo %s",name,mode);
  }

  return fp;
}
```

**doble puntero**

```
int openFile(FILE **fp,const char *name,const char *mode,int CON_SIN)
{
  *fp = fopen(name,mode);

  if(!*fp)
  {
    if(CON_SIN)
        fprintf(stderr,"No se pudo abrir %s, en modo %s",name,mode);
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Un saludo.