# Manejo correcto de punteros

Tags: c, shell, punteros

Estoy teniendo problemas para realizar las implementaciones de algunos de los comandos de shell en C. 
Bajo mi punto de vista parece que es por un incorrecto manejo de punteros en C (llevo poco aprendiendo este lenguaje). 
Por el momento estoy intentando implementar las funciones de cambio de directorio y export, aunque el cambio de directorio funciona cuando escribo el path al directorio al cual quiero moverme en el propio código. No lo hace cuando ese path es introducido por el usuario. Estoy casi seguro de que se debe a ese `args[1]` que paso como argumento. Lo mismo ocurre con el export aunque en este caso directamente de violación de segmento. He intentado imprimir args[1] como veréis en el código pero da violación de segmento al hacer eso. Agradecería que alguien me pudiera echar una mano para aprender a hacer esto que quiero hacer correctamente.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define PROMPT "$"
#define MAX_LINE 512


int parse_args(char **args, char *line){
    int n=0;
    char* token;
    char delimit[]=" \t\r\n\v\f";
    token=strtok(line,delimit);
    while(token!=NULL){
        printf("token%i: %s\n",n,token);
        args=token;
        n++;
        args++;
        token=strtok(NULL,delimit);
    }
    printf("token%i: %s\n",n,token);
    args=token;
    return n;
}

char *read_line(char *line){
    printf("%s%s ",getenv("USER"),PROMPT);
    fflush(stdout);
    line=fgets(line,MAX_LINE,stdin);
    return line;
}


int execute_line(char *line){
    char **args;
    parse_args(args,line);
    check_internal(args);
    return 0;
}

int check_internal(char **args){
    if( strcmp(args, "cd")==0 ){
        internal_cd();
    } else{
        if( strcmp(args, "export")==0 ){
            internal_export();
        }else{
            if( strcmp(args, "source")==0 ){
                internal_source();
            }else{
                if( strcmp(args, "jobs")==0 ){
                    internal_jobs();
                }else{

                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int internal_cd(char **args){
    char buff[50];
    printf("Comando cd \n");
    char directorio []= "/home/jamengual1/Escritorio/FlashDRIVE";
    printf("%s", args+1);
    if (chdir(directorio) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error %d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        perror("Error");
        return -1;
    } else{
        printf("Estás en el directorio: %s \n", getcwd(buff, 50));
        return 1;
    }

}

   //así es como tendría que ser pasándole args pero me da Bad Address todo el rato
/*int internal_cd(char **args){
    printf("%s","cambio de directorio\n");
    char buff[50];
    printf("Comando cd \n");
    //printf("%s", args[1]); //violación de segmento
    if (chdir(args[1]) == -1)
    {
        //fprintf(stderr, "Error %d: %s\n", errno,strerror(errno));
        perror("Error");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Estás en el directorio: %s \n", getcwd(buff, 50));
    return 1;

}
*/

int internal_export(char **args) {
    printf("%s","éste es el export\n");
    char *variable;
    char *nuevo_valor;
    char *aux;

    variable = strtok(args[1], "=");
    nuevo_valor = strtok(NULL, args[1]);
    aux = getenv(variable);

    if((int)aux == -1)
    {
        perror("Error: getenv");
        return -1;
    }
        printf("VAR: '%s'. Valor: '%s'. Nuevo valor: '%s'\n", variable, aux, nuevo_valor);

    if(!nuevo_valor){
        perror("Error: error de sintaxis");
        return -1;

    }

        if ((setenv(variable,nuevo_valor,1)== -1))
        {

            perror("Error: llamada al sistema con setenv");
            return -1;

        }

        aux = getenv(variable);

        if((int)aux == -1)
        {
             perror("Error: llamada al sistema con getenv");
            return -1;

        }

        printf("Nuevo valor: '%s': '%s'\n", variable, aux);
        return 1;        

}



int internal_source(char **args) {
    printf("%s","éste es el source\n");
    return 1;
}

int internal_jobs(char **args){
    printf("%s","éste es el jobs\n");
    return 1;
}

void main(){
    char line[MAX_LINE]; 
    while(read_line(line)){
        execute_line(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
char *read_line(char *line){
    printf("%s%s ",getenv("USER"),PROMPT);
    fflush(stdout);
    line=fgets(line,MAX_LINE,stdin);
    return line;
}
```

Siendo estrictos, esa función debería quedar así:

```
char *read_line(char *line){
    printf("%s%s ",getenv("USER"),PROMPT);
    fflush(stdout);
    return fgets(line,MAX_LINE,stdin);
}
```

Si no el resultado es un poco engañoso, porque al llegar al final del fichero, ´line´ apuntará a 0 pero dicho cambio de puntero no se va a reflejar fuera de la función:

```
void func(int* ptr)
{
  ptr = 0;
}

int main()
{
  int* ptr = 1000;
  func(ptr);

  // Pregunta: ¿Cuanto vale ptr aqui?
  // Respuesta: 100
}
```

Y ahora sí nos centramos en el error:

```
int execute_line(char *line){
    char **args; // (1)
    parse_args(args,line);
    check_internal(args);
    return 0;
}

int parse_args(char **args, char *line){
    int n=0;
    char* token;
    char delimit[]=" \t\r\n\v\f";
    token=strtok(line,delimit);
    while(token!=NULL){
        printf("token%i: %s\n",n,token);
        args=token; // (2) (3)
        n++;
        args++;
        token=strtok(NULL,delimit);
    }
    printf("token%i: %s\n",n,token);
    args=token; // (4)
    return n;
}
```

- (1): `args` es un puntero doble y no está inicializado. ¿A dónde apunta? A cualquier parte menos a una posición de memoria debidamente inicializada
- (2) asignas un valor a `args`, que no está inicializado luego estás sobreescribiendo memoria que no te pertenece.
- (3) `args` es `char**` y `token` es `char*`. Son tipos diferentes y el resultado de esa asignación no puede ser bueno.
- (4) ¿Qué pretendes con esta última asignación?

Si quieres almacenar una lista en `args` tienes varias opciones:

1. Calculas previamente el número de elementos a almacenar y haces la reserva de memoria que corresponda. En este caso junto con `args` tendrás que facilitar una variable que diga cual es el número de elementos que contiene.
2. Asumes un número máximo y haces que `args` tenga un tamaño fijo. En este caso también sería recomendable indicar el número efectivo de valores que almacena.

Un ejemplo con memoria dinámica:

```
int execute_line(char *line){
    char **args;
    int nargs;
    parse_args(&args,&nargs,line); // parse_args requiere un puntero triple
    check_internal(args);
    free(args);
    return 0;
}

int parse_args(char ***args, int* nargs char *line){
    int n=0;
    const char delimit[]=" \t\r\n\v\f";

    *nargs = 0;
    char cadTemp[MAX_LINE];
    strcpy(cadTemp,line);
    char* token=strtok(cadTemp,delimit)
    while( token )
    {
      *nargs++;
      token=strtok(NULL,delimit);
    }

    *args = malloc(*nargs * sizeof(char*);
    token=strtok(linea,delimit)
    while(token!=NULL){
        printf("token%i: %s\n",n,token);
        **args=token;
        n++;
        (*args)++;
        token=strtok(NULL,delimit);
    }
    printf("token%i: %s\n",n,token);
    return n;
}
```

¿Por qué necesitas un puntero triple? Porque si no los cambios serán locales (Esto lo he explicado ya en otras preguntas, como por ejemplo [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24224/segmentation-fault-file/24287#24287)

Comment: 1. En lugar de definir un número fijo de argumentos  para el malloc, se podría hacer definiendo un array de x elementos a modo de buffer? 2. Dado que el enunciado de esta práctica especifica exactamente como tienen que ser las funciones y sus argumentos no puedo incluir un triple puntero. He entendido el motivo pero necesitaría hacerlo de otra manera. Gracias por la respuesta de todas formas

Comment: Para poder hacerlo así tendrías que saber de antemano el tamaño máximo que puede ocupar cada elemento

Answer (score 2):

Tu código contenía bastantes errores.

Esta es mi versión, manteniendo la interfaz de tus funciones intactas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PROMPT "$"
#define MAX_LINE 512

#define DELIMS " \t\r\n\v\f"

int parse_args( char **args, char *line){
  int n = 0; // Contador de palabras.
  char *token = strtok( line, DELIMS );

  while( token ) {
    args[n] = token;
    ++n;
    token = strtok( NULL, DELIMS );
  }
  return n;
}

char *read_line( char *line ){
  printf( "%s%s ", getenv( "USER" ), PROMPT );
  fflush( stdout );
  return fgets( line, MAX_LINE, stdin );
}

int execute_line( char *line ){
  char *args[MAX_LINE/2]; // NO puede haber mas de MAX_LINE / 2 ordenes.

  memset( args, 0, MAX_LINE ); // Por seguridad.
  parse_args( args, line );

  return check_internal( args );
}

int check_internal( char **args ) {
  if( !strcmp( args[0], "cd" ) ) {
    return internal_cd( args );
  } else
  if( !strcmp(args[0], "export" ) ) {
    return internal_export( args );
  } else
  if( !strcmp( args[0], "source" ) ) {
    return internal_source();
  } else
  if( !strcmp(args[0], "jobs" ) ) {
    return internal_jobs( );
  } else
  return -1;
}

int internal_cd( char **args ){
  char buff[MAX_LINE];
  int ret;

  if( !args[1] ) {
    printf( "Debe indicar una ruta.\n" );
  } else {
    if( chdir( args[1] ) == -1 ) {
      fprintf( stderr, "Error: %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
      return -1;
    }
    getcwd( buff, MAX_LINE );
    printf( "Estas en la ruta %s\n", buff );
  }
  return 1;
}

int internal_export( char **args ) {
  char buff[MAX_LINE];
  char *old;
  int ret;

  if( args[1] && args[2] ) {
    old = getenv( args[1] );
    printf( "Valor antiguo: %s\n", old ? old : "SIN ASIGNAR" );
    if( setenv( args[1], args[2], 1 ) == -1 ) {
      fprintf( stderr, "Error: %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
      return -1;
    }
    printf( "Valor nuevo: %s\n", args[2] );
  } else {
    fprintf( stderr, "Error. Uso: export <nombre> <valor>\n" );
  }
  return 1;
}

int internal_source(char **args) {
  printf("%s","éste es el source\n");
  return 1;
}

int internal_jobs(char **args){
    printf("%s","éste es el jobs\n");
    return 1;
}

void main( ) {
  char line[MAX_LINE]; 

  while( read_line( line ) ) {
    execute_line( line );
  }
}
```

No te detallo todas las modificaciones porque, sinceramente, han sido bastantes y no las recuerdo.
Como se mantiene la interfaz de tus funciones, puedes compararlas.

**EDITO**

El **gran truco** está en las funciones `execute_line( )` y `parse_args( )`:

- En `execute_line( )`, creamos un *array de punteros* para guardar precisamente eso, punteros a los *tokens* que nos pasó el usuario.
   ¿ Porqué `[MAX_LINE / 2]` ? Muy fácil. El peor caso posible es que el usuario pasara algo como `"a b c d e f g h"`. En ese caso, por cada 2 caracteres, tendríamos un *token*; de ahí el `/ 2`. Cualquier otra entrada contendrá menos tokes.
- En `parse_args( )` recibimos el `array` que creamos en la función anterior. `strtok( )` **modifica** su primer argumento, insertando `0` en donde encuentra delimitadores, y devuelve punteros a los *tokens* creados. Nosotros nos limitamos a guardar esos punteros. No es necesario nada mas, `strtok( )` se encarga de todo, y *reutilizamos* la línea original introducida por el usuario en el resto del programa.

¿ Cuantos tokes introdujo el usuario ? No lo sabemos; pero si sabemos que `args[]` se rellenó con `0`, así que el primero *token* **no valido** es un puntero nulo. Nos basta con comprobarlo.

Pd.
Que `NULL == 0 == <FALSE>` es el mejor invento del mundo mundial !!